# How to fully automate the Google Cloud Build trigger creation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

i try to fully automate the cloud build trigger creation via sh script

As source I use Github.

So far it's possible to create the trigger

```
gcloud beta builds triggers create github \
  --repo-name=organisation/repo \
  --repo-owner=organisation \
  --branch-pattern="^main$" \
  --build-config=cloudbuild.yaml
```

BUT each repo has to be authorized manually before otherwise you get the Error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.builds.triggers.create.github) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Repository mapping does not exist. Please visit https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers/connect?project=********* to connect a repository to your project
```

Which links me to the UI to create the authorization manually

Is there a way to also automate that step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to connect to external repositories using the API, but there is an ongoing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/142550612) for this to be implemented.

There are two options you can adopt now:

1. **Connect all the repositories at once** from the Cloud Console. This way, you will be able to automate the creation of triggers for those repositories.
2. Use **Cloud Source Repositories**, which are connected to Cloud Build by default, as indicated [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#connect_repo). Check this  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes) on how to create a remote repository in CSR from a local git repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you use another hosted Git provider, such as on GitHub or Bitbucket, and still need to mirror the repository into Cloud Source Repositories, you must have the cloudbuilds.builds.create permission for the Google Cloud project with which you're working. This permission is typically granted through the cloudbuild.builds.editor role.

Here are some links to this [information.](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/integrating-with-cloud-build)
[Creating and managing build trigger](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#connect_repo)